# Keyboard hides soft buttons (back, home, recent buttons)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, textinput

I've written a sidebar app that is always available and draws directly to the window. If the user has a phone without hardware buttons and he starts typing into an `EditText` the button bar (that is part of the display because of the missing hardware buttons) with the back/home/recent buttons is hidden.

How can I prevent that?